# Why do I get an IOException in sending an email with Gmail service?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

In my android test application, after that i got the JSON file from the Google Developer Console, where i had set on the Gmail API, and that i have put it in the emulator, i get an IOException which says:

> "com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException:
>   403 Forbidden {   "code" : 403,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "usageLimits",
>       "message" : "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
>       "reason" : "accessNotConfigured"   } ],   "message" : "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API
>   for your project." }"

I think that I must use a GoogleClientSecrets object, but i haven't found its use.

Here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
    final String SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose";
    final String FILE_NAME = "TestEmail5.json";
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;

    Button button;

    OnClickListener sendListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            new sendEmailTask().execute();

        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(sendListener);


    }


    public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String bodyText) throws MessagingException 
    {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

            email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setText(bodyText);

            return email;
    }


    public static void sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
            Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
            message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

            System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
            System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
    }


    public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email) throws MessagingException, IOException 
    {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            email.writeTo(bytes);
            String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
            return message;
    }


    public class sendEmailTask extends AsyncTask
    {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)
        {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            String token = "";

            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
            Account account[] = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

            String accountName = account[0].name;

            try 
            {
                //GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,  new java.io.FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "//" + "JSON/" + FILE_NAME));


                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, accountName, SCOPE);

                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);

                Gmail service =  new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("TestEmail5").build();

                MimeMessage mm = createEmail("myemail", "myemail", "soggetto", "oggetto");

                sendMessage(service, "myemail", mm);

            } 
            catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) 
            {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (GoogleAuthException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (MessagingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

    };







}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to login to http://console.developers.google.com/ and create a project and activate the "Gmail" API for it.

Documented more at:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_1_enable_the_gmail_api

Comment: I can't use a web view to get authentication, in my final project it must be done in background without user interaction.

Comment: Your developer account that you used to create the "project" and get oauth2 set up needs to have this done.  The code seems fine, as does how you're doing the authorization, you just haven't set up the project (oauth2 developer key) completely yet.

Comment: So is the json useless?

Comment: client_secrets.json?  you still need it, anyway you haven't finished setting up the developer project in your web browser as a one time thing, you need to do that before you can use the API.  the docs i linked to should explain it all.

Comment: More details?  Were you able to activate the Gmail API through the developers console in your web browser?  If so, now what happens when you run the same code?

Comment: yes, and it gave the same error (i have also activated all api's)

Comment: Hi. I am having the same issue. always getting error 403 when trying to do any Gmail API actions. Did you manage to solve it?